# Как компактно записать "Исключающее ИЛИ"?

Tags: python, алгоритм, golang, логические-выражения, булева-алгебра

Как реализовать исключающее или? В большинстве языков эта конструкция не реализована на уровне языка. Поэтому приходится писать неочевидные конструкции вида:

```
!a && b || b && !a
```

Это можно завернуть в функцию, разумеется:

```
xor(a, b)
```

Но нельзя исключать человеческий фактор, который часто может приводить к конструкциям вида:

```
!variable.very_long_name_field_1.very_long_subname_field && variable.very_long_name_field_1.very_long_subname_field_a || variable.very_long_name_field_1.very_long_subname_field && !variable.very_long_name_field_1.very_long_subname_field_a
```

В качестве ответа приведите компактный пример вычисления XOR (исключающего или).

Comment: На базисе {&&, ||, !} есть только два варианта: ваш и (a || b) && (!a || !b)

Comment: Без разницы как. Я говорю про максимальную читаемость кода. Именно это важно. Код пишется для людей, а не для машин

Comment: В Паскале есть операция XOR, если мне не изменяет память. Это и есть самый компактный вариант. Скажите на каком базисе реализовывать эту операцию, иначе невозможно дать ответ.

Comment: + это всё очень зависит от правил языка. Иногда xor можно заменить битовой операцией ^. Иногда можно взять сумму по модулю 2. Но не всегда это будет универсальный вариант.

Comment: + в языках бывает ленивое выполнение операций, когда вычисляютя не все выражения. Поэтому варианты с XOR или !(a == b) не будут являться эквивалентной заменой  вариантам на базисе {&&, ||, !}

Comment: @КириллМалышев интересует python, goland

Comment: Для Boolean (a xor b) === (a != b)

Comment: @hedgehogues, я думаю, лучше тогда задать отдельные вопросы по обоим языкам.

Comment: С помощью функции проще это делать. Ф-я пишется очень легко - создаёте бул переменную. В цикле прогоняете все аргументы. Если аргумент = true, то приравниваем переменную true. Если уже true, то возвращаем false. После цикла возвращаем эту переменную

Comment: Как-то непонятно - написано о возможности завернуть в функцию, и тут же о "человеческом факторе", который ее использовать откажется. Тогда никаких вариантов даже в языках с соответствующим оператором - "человеческий фактор" его может похерить и использовать что-то неудобочитаемое. Так что вопрос стоит как-то не так...

Comment: @КириллМалышев  "в языках бывает ленивое выполнение операций" для xor очень сложно сделать "ленивое вычисление". По факту - невозможно.

Comment: @KoVadim, правильно, имелось в виду ленивое выполнение для || и &&. Из-за этого варианты через XOR и через {||, &&, !} могут работать по-разному. Там даже, скорее, дело в том, что a и b два раза в одном выражении встречаются.

Comment: @KoVadim ленивое -- это кейс, когда ненужные члены далее не проверяются?

Comment: @hedgehogues, да, но это всё может вызвать проблемы только в случаях, если у a и/или b есть побочные эффекты или их вычисление ресурсозатратно.

Comment: @hedgehogues ленивое вычисление хорошо понять на таком `b != 0 && a/b > 1`. Если ленивых вычислений нет, можно получить деление на ноль.

Comment: @KoVadim ну так если XOR будет записываться как, например `a~b`, то не нужны ленивые вычисления.

Comment: не понятен комментарий. Как бы Вы не записывали сам xor, его сущность от этого не поменяется. Или Вы смотрите на начальное предложение `!a && b || b && !a` - тут да, работает ленивое вычисление.

Comment: @KoVadim зачем ленивые вычисления, если операция атомарная?

Comment: я думаю, наши пути размышлений разошлись

Comment: я не пойму почему все пишут ответы для bool...

Comment: @eri, в вопросе тег "логические выражения", т.ч. речь не про побитовые операции. Хотя они иногда могут заменить логические.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для булевых значений, в go ответ будет таким:

```
if boolA != boolB {

}
```

Результат сравнения равен true только если один из операндов true, а второй false, т.е. не равны друг другу. Именно так и работает xor.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27211124

Comment: Кто-то даже пытался (безуспешно) предложить встроить в язык оператор `^` и для булевых значений: [XOR operation on bool](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6304)

Answer (score 5):

Для python:

```
bool(a) != bool(b)
```

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433161/7485582) [A. Coady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36433/a-coady)

Answer (score 5):

```
bool(a) ^ bool(b)
```

---

Когда `a` и/или `b` уже типа `bool`, не надо к нему — конечно — применить функцию `bool()`, но *нужно не забыть использовать **скобки***, например

```
(5 > 4) ^ (1 > 7)     # True
```

Answer (score 1):

А что, никто не заметил ошибку у автора? В его ответе:

```
!a && b || b && !a
```

Первая часть: `!a && b` то же самое что и вторая часть: `b && !a`
Я заметил, но подумал что я чего то не понимаю и напечатал как есть в Kotlin, но IntelliJ Idea сразу предупредила что я написал фигню какую то, но я упорствовал и запустил код как есть и получил ответ который совсем не есть **XOR**

Надо исправить:

```kotlin
!a && b || a && !b
```

тогда будет **XOR**